# Understand podfile structures and use case

Tags: ios, swift, kotlin, cocoapods, kotlin-multiplatform

Hey I am learning Kmm with cocoapods integration. My studio is generated podfile automatically when I added the KMM module. Sometag I understand but some are not. Can someone guide me use case of attributes and also did I miss any attributes for my ios project.

**[Podile](https://github.com/vivek-modi/MultiplatformProject/blob/master/app/kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule/kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule.podspec)**

```
 ​Pod​::​Spec​.​new​ ​do​ |​spec​| 
 ​    ​spec​.​name​                     ​=​ ​'kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule' 
 ​    ​spec​.​version​                  ​=​ ​'1.0' 
 ​    ​spec​.​homepage​                 ​=​ ​'https://github.com/vivek-modi/MultiplatformProject' 
 ​    ​spec​.​source​                   ​=​ ​{​ ​:git​ ​=>​ ​"Not Published"​,​ ​:tag​ ​=>​ ​"Cocoapods/​#{​spec​.​name​}​/​#{​spec​.​version​}​"​ ​} 
 ​    ​spec​.​authors​                  ​=​ ​'vivekmodi456@gmail.com' 
 ​    ​spec​.​license​                  ​=​ ​'' 
 ​    ​spec​.​summary​                  ​=​ ​'Some description for the Shared Module' 
  
 ​    ​spec​.​vendored_frameworks​      ​=​ ​"build/cocoapods/framework/kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule.framework" 
 ​    ​spec​.​libraries​                ​=​ ​"c++" 
 ​    ​spec​.​module_name​              ​=​ ​"​#{​spec​.​name​}​_umbrella" 
  
 ​    ​spec​.​ios​.​deployment_target​ ​=​ ​'14.1' 
  
 ​    ​spec​.​pod_target_xcconfig​ ​=​ ​{ 
 ​        ​'KOTLIN_PROJECT_PATH'​ ​=>​ ​':app:kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule'​, 
 ​        ​'PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME'​ ​=>​ ​'kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule'​, 
 ​    ​} 
  
 ​    ​spec​.​script_phases​ ​=​ ​[ 
 ​        ​{ 
 ​            ​:name​ ​=>​ ​'Build kotlinmultiplatformsharedmodule'​, 
 ​            ​:execution_position​ ​=>​ ​:before_compile​, 
 ​            ​:shell_path​ ​=>​ ​'/bin/sh'​, 
 ​            ​:script​ ​=>​ ​<<-SCRIPT 
 ​                if [ "YES" = "$COCOAPODS_SKIP_KOTLIN_BUILD" ]; then 
 ​                  echo "Skipping Gradle build task invocation due to COCOAPODS_SKIP_KOTLIN_BUILD environment variable set to ​\"​YES​\"​" 
 ​                  exit 0 
 ​                fi 
 ​                set -ev 
 ​                REPO_ROOT="$PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT" 
 ​                "$REPO_ROOT/../../gradlew" -p "$REPO_ROOT" $KOTLIN_PROJECT_PATH:syncFramework ​\ 
 ​                    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.platform=$PLATFORM_NAME ​\ 
 ​                    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.archs="$ARCHS" ​\ 
 ​                    -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.configuration=$CONFIGURATION 
 ​            SCRIPT 
 ​        ​} 
 ​    ​] 
 ​end
```

> 1. I have doubt in **source**, **vendored_framework**, **libraries**, **module_name** and what is **pod_tarvet_xconfig**.

> 2. Did I miss any other attributes for my ios project?

> 3. Can someone explain me how this pod is know where the framework is? If I add this pod file to different repository so how can I connect them.

My whole Kmm [project](https://github.com/vivek-modi/MultiplatformProject)

Comment: You don't need to worry about this file, and especially edit, it should be added into `Podfile` of your ios app (it's done if you've created a multiplatform app from the wizard), the rest is just must have data generated by the plugin. If you need to modify it, the only way is `cocoapods` section in your `build.gradle` file, which is well documented.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov i need to know 3 point is every important for me. Do you have idea about that ?

Comment: cocoapods plugin won't let you do that, it calls `gradlew` to build the framework, so it needs all the source files. If you need to distribute iOS framework, you can build the project and copy it from `build/cocoapods/framework/yourModule.framework`, or [build it](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-mobile-understand-project-structure.html#ios-framework) without cocoapods plugin, to get the same framework. If you need to distrube KMM library, there're some articles about how to do that.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov can you share me that article ?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-publish-lib.html